# Partial response for Google Contacts API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-contacts-api

For one of the applications I have developed some very limited number of users are reporting following error:

`[10/1/2019 8:34:47 PM | Debug] Inner Exception Type: System.FormatException
[10/1/2019 8:34:47 PM | Debug]  Inner Exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
[10/1/2019 8:34:47 PM | Debug]  Inner Source: mscorlib
[10/1/2019 8:34:47 PM | Debug]  Inner Stack Trace:    at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at Google.GData.Extensions.When.CreateInstance(XmlNode node, AtomFeedParser parser)
   at Google.GData.Extensions.SimpleContainer.ProcessChildNodes(XmlNode node, AtomFeedParser parser)
   at Google.GData.Extensions.SimpleContainer.CreateInstance(XmlNode node, AtomFeedParser parser)
   at Google.GData.Client.AtomEntry.Parse(ExtensionElementEventArgs e, AtomFeedParser parser)
   at Google.GData.Client.ExtensionElementEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, ExtensionElementEventArgs e)
   at Google.GData.Client.AtomFeed.OnNewExtensionElement(Object sender, ExtensionElementEventArgs e)
   at Google.GData.Client.BaseFeedParser.OnNewExtensionElement(XmlNode node, AtomBase baseObject)
   at Google.GData.Client.BaseFeedParser.OnNewExtensionElement(XmlReader reader, AtomBase baseObject)
   at Google.GData.Client.AtomFeedParser.ParseExtensionElements(XmlReader reader, AtomBase baseObject)
   at Google.GData.Client.AtomFeedParser.ParseEntry(XmlReader reader)
   at Google.GData.Client.AtomFeedParser.ParseSource(XmlReader reader, AtomSource source)
   at Google.GData.Client.AtomFeedParser.ParseFeed(XmlReader reader, AtomFeed feed)
   at Google.GData.Client.AtomFeedParser.Parse(Stream streamInput, AtomFeed feed)
[10/1/2019 8:34:47 PM | Debug]  Exception Type: Google.GData.Client.ClientFeedException
[10/1/2019 8:34:47 PM | Debug]  Exception: Parsing failed
[10/1/2019 8:34:47 PM | Debug]  Source: Google.GData.Client
[10/1/2019 8:34:47 PM | Debug]  Stack Trace:    at Google.GData.Client.AtomFeedParser.Parse(Stream streamInput, AtomFeed feed)
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.CreateAndParseFeed(Stream inputStream, Uri uriToUse)
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(FeedQuery feedQuery)
   at Google.GData.Client.Feed`1.get_AtomFeed()
   at Google.GData.Client.Feed`1.<get_Entries>d__0.MoveNext()`

Possibly one of the contact has incorrect birthday date or some other field with invalid date.  Interestingly I am not able to replicate such situation i.e. despite several tries I am not able to create such contact.

Now I am trying to implement some debug routine and check on which contact parsing fails.  I am trying to implement partial get using Google Contacts API,  but I am not able to find proper combination for query string.  To test I am using OAuth Playground and for testing I am trying to retrieve only Id field.  Here is what I tried:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/defaule/full?fields=entry/gd:id

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/defaule/full?fields=id

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/defaule/full?fields=gd:id

And many more.... I am always getting HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.   What is correct way to get only selected contact fields using Google Contacts API?

Comment: Your  code is expecting a xml response.  When an error occurs you are getting instead of a normal http response of 200 OK you are getting an error (status 400) and not returning xny xml.  The interesting part of the response is the http 1.1.  Http 1.0 is stream mode and http 1.1 is chunk mode.  the best way of debugging is to use a sniffer like wireshark of fiddler and compare the first request on a good system and bad system.   Check the header to see if they are the same.  The default header can be different on different machines.

Comment: You can force http 1.0 using following :             HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("URL");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: I am able to see complete reply in OAuth Playground so for example for request https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/defaule/full?fields=entry/gd:id I am getting reply like: `
{
  "error": {
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", 
    "code": 400, 
    "details": [
      {
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "entry.gd:id", 
            "description": "Error expanding 'fields' parameter. Cannot find matching fields for path 'entry.gd:id'."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: I found following link : https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3  Why are you using "defaule" instead of "default".  Are you working with a Sweedish language webpage?  the error may have something to do with the language used on webpage.  It looks like the "entry" should be a {ContactId} but not sure of the format.

Comment: It is not working also with "default".

Comment: Look like you have more than one issue if default is failing.  The link I provided has lots of example.  I not sure of the format.   I do not use this API.  For Net library the website says use following : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth